# Typescript: Calling a static function that has `this` parameter

Tags: typescript

I'm currently hitting a wall in typescript.

Basically, I want to call a static function from a class extending a specific abstract class.

I get the following error

`The 'this' context of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'AStatic<AStatic<unknown>>'. Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.`

Here is a link to a [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggysAhsAlgYwDxyhAHsCAOwBMBnWAPigF4oBvKQiAdwAoBKALimwF8BuAFCDEAI1LAATojTAoaADaJS5GPUFQoE5OnmIFChDszY8BEqqOoTFCq2AALFKW7wk1rBXbrNmtAHtCUn8FCAA6BX8Ac1YAcgcIEFj2DSheQXTBRWVyACEcfCIyWHVMrKUVKAARAvNitToM4XKcqABhHyhEABVwCG5QSH8AM1ghP0CJSQBXWX9Jez6BvpHYb0bfKEdnMJ6+mi2+8d9t0l3eyDC0fUN3dA5j9MyAoLk0A6ZmdtZc9iEXiTyAD6ACYPixvlU-kA)

Here is the code:

```js
type AStatic<S extends A> = { new(): S };

abstract class A {
  static callStatic<S extends AStatic<S>>(this: AStatic<S>) {
    console.log('hey')
  }
}

class B extends A {
}


class D extends A {
}

class C {
  aType: typeof A;
  constructor(type: typeof A) {
    this.aType = type;
    this.aType.callStatic(); // error is here
  }
}

const c = new C(B);
const c_2 = new C(D);
```

The only way I managed to make it build in typescript is by passing `any` like the instead of `typeof A`. It's just a shame because I get no support from my IDE for the functions of A.

Note that I don't have control over class A and type AStatic, since those are from an external libray.

Comment: @ConnorLow Do you mean the `this` which is passed as a parameter to the static function? If so, as I stated, I have no control over the function definition since it's in an external library. I only have control over classes B, C and D

Comment: I retract my comment. I see that you are using `typeof A` not `A`. Totally different senario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close! Take a look your pseudo-definition for `A`:

```
abstract class A {
  static callStatic<S extends AStatic<S>>(this: AStatic<S>) {
  //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //           the `this` parameter must be type AStatic<A>
```

And looking at `AStatic`:

```
type AStatic<S extends A> = { new(): A };
//                            ^^^^^ - type must have a constructor, 
//                                      which rules out abstract classes.
```

This rules out `typeof A` as the `this` parameter, since it is `abstract`. We could try using `AStatic` directly:

```
class C {
  aType: AStatic<A>;
  constructor(type: AStatic<A>) {
    this.aType = type;
    this.aType.callStatic();
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^ - Property 'callStatic' does not exist on type 'AStatic<A>'
  }
}
```

But `callStatic` is not defined on `AStatic`. The solution is an intersection type:

```
class C {
  aType: AStatic<A> & typeof A
  constructor(type: AStatic<A> & typeof A) {
    this.aType = type;
    this.aType.callStatic() // works!
  }
}
```

As *MunsMan* pointed out though, unless you override `callStatic` on your derived types you don't need to pass `typeof A` at all:

```
const c = new C(B);
c.callStatic(); // hey
B.callStatic(); // hey
D.callStatic(); // hey
```

In other words, as long as you have a non-abstract version of `A`, you can call `callStatic` (or any static method/property) on that type and it will work the same way every time!

Comment: Hmm did I miss something? I tried your solution in typescript playground and it doesn't seem to be working for me, i get the following error `this.aType.prototype.callStatic is not a function`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggysAhsAlgYwDxyhAHsCAOwBMBnWAPigF4oBvKQiAdwAoBKALligF8BuAFCDEAI1LAATojTAoaADaJS5GPUFQoE5OnmIFChDszY8BEqqOoTFCq2AALFKW7wk1rBXbrNmtAHtCUn8FCAA6BX8Ac1YAcgcIEFj2DT5BXmFFZXIAIRx8IjIeOnThQSyVKAARfPMitRKMzKVKgGEoDAAVWsLVKhLNRE7wCFcrdC6KIT9AiUkAV1l-SXsRsfcJzq8fX0dnMKGRmihQSGndp1ID4cgwsEl-YEeRsLR9Qw20DnOMpoCguRoY5MZhQVqsHLsIT-CTyAD6ACZgSwwawqlCgA
I

Comment: Sorry, fixed and tested my answer. Should be good now!

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I didn't know we could make union types! It works for me :)

Comment: @Solal I made a correction. They are actually called Intersection types for `&`. `|` is a union; my bad. Still works the same though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call an explicit instance of A, which is not necessary.

```
type AStatic<S extends A> = { new(): A };

abstract class A {
    static callStatic<S extends AStatic<S>>(this: AStatic<S>) {
        console.log('hey')
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

class C {
    aType: typeof A;
    constructor(type: typeof A) {
        this.aType = type;
        B.callStatic()
    }
}

const c = new C(B);
```

Because the method callStatic is static, you can just call the implementation of this method in B.

Comment: Well, to be more specific, in my case, I have many classes extending A, and need to be able to call the static function on anyone of them, not just B. I updated my question to better represent my case.